# SwiftUI: How to center a view vertically and horizontally inside of a container view and put something under it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I searched stackoverflow, but unfortunately didn't find a solution to this particular case.

I try to display following scenario:

- a container view
- a Text that is centered horizontally and vertically in that container view
- a Text that is below this centered Text

Whatever I try I can't center that Text horizontally and vertically in the container view and put something underneath it, without putting it out of the center of the container view.

For better understanding, I portrayed this behaviour in a storyboard:

[image]

It would be great if somebody could help me code this scenario in SwiftUI! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is possible approach (at least for start) that I would prefer, because both labels remains independent, and always be centered in parent container by primary text.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoCenteredText: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            ZStack {
                Text("Primary Text").font(.title)
                    .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center, computeValue: { $0[.bottom] })
                    .position(x: gp.size.width / 2, y: gp.size.height / 2)
                Text("Secondary Text")
                    .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center, computeValue: { $0[.top] - 16 })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `.position` in above fixes primary title at center of parent container, which free space is consumed by `GeometryReader`, and `alignmentGuide` force layout to place secondary text at offset 16 from bottom of primary text (actually in the same way as constraint in your question).

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World! Centereed")
                .overlay(Text("john").offset(y: 30))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is better than my solution, but there is one problem: I need to support dynamic font size for accessibility, so a fixed offset is a problem. :(