# animating opacity is also animating position of views

Tags: animation, swiftui

I'm using .offset and .overlay of an image to add Text objects so that their positions are exactly where I want them. I then animate the opacity of the Text("Checking network...")

The problem is that as opacity is animated the image position animates from its correct position to 0,0 (top left) and back. (The overlay texts also move with the image)

I've tried all sorts of permutations including removing the .offset modifiers but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var opacity: Double = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(
            sidebar: {
                FetchLessonsView()
            }, content: {
                Text("middleView")
            }, detail: {
                Text("detail")
            }
        )
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct FetchLessonsView: View {
    @State private var opacity: Double = 1
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "person")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
            .offset(y: -31.5)
            .overlay(
                Text("person").offset(y: 57)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
            )
            .overlay(
                Text("Checking network...").offset(y: 117)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .onAppear {
                        let baseAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)
                        let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                        withAnimation(repeated) {
                            opacity = 0
                        }
                    }
                    .opacity(opacity)
            )
    }
}
```

(edited to include enclosing NavigationSplitView)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. In any case, why do you extensively use hardcoded `offset`s in the first place? This just looks like a `VStack` to me.

Comment: @Sweeper because the views accurately reproduce my launch image - with the addition of the "Checking network" text

Comment: Okay, please show some code that actually reproduces the issue then. And anyway, I'm pretty sure you can reproduce your launch image or whatever that is with `VStack`s too.

Comment: @Sweeper ... I've edited the question to include enclosing NavigationSplitView -  I've tested the edited code it in a new project and the problem still occurs

Comment: Ah, it's [that thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64945040/5133585) with navigation stack/split views again. IMO this is a SwiftUI bug. Anyway you just need to start the animation with a slight delay. See the linked post.

Comment: @Sweeper - this gives me hope but I can't seem to get it to work - where did you code the delay and geometry reader if it's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *sweeper* was suggesting in the comments, if you want the components of the view to be vertically arranged then it would probably be a much better idea to be using a `VStack`. To put it another way, using offsets for layout is usually not a good idea.

Here is an example of how the view can be built with a `VStack`. Above all, it means you can avoid using offsets completely. Padding is used to reserve space for the blinking message and the message is shown as an overlay in this space.

*EDIT* Updated in response to your edit to include a workaround for the actual cause of the animation issue.

```swift
struct FetchLessonsView: View {
    @State private var opacity: Double = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "person")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
            Text("person")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 40)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Text("Checking network...")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .font(.title3)
                .opacity(opacity)
                .animation(
                    .easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
                    value: opacity
                )
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                opacity = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My method follows this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234986/3858484 to the question - SwiftUI: How to center a view vertically and horizontally inside of a container view and put something under it (although my image is not centered vertically)

Answer (score -1):

```
var body: some View {
      Image(systemName: "person")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
        .offset(y: -31.5)
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Text("person").offset(y: 57)
            }
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
        )
        .overlay(
            Text("Checking network...").offset(y: 117)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .font(.title3)
                .onAppear {
                    let baseAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)
                    let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                    withAnimation(repeated) {
                        opacity = 0
                }
                 .opacity(opacity)
        }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).